# Unknown cipher error when creating cipher using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptoapi

I am converting the Java logic encryption to Node JS.

My encryption key is 24 char base64 string as you see below. In java, it is decoded as byte[] and used for encryption. So in NodeJS, I don't know what is the best way to do it.
But I am doing `Buffer.from(key, 'base64')` while creating the cipher. Is this correct? I am getting an `Unknown Cipher`. I tried with different algorithm modes. No luck.

**Can someone please suggest which algorithm mode and IV key for creating cipher using 24 char base 64 string?**

Would the cipher final value be the same between JAVA and NODE JS to make sure the conversion is correct before using the encryption URL?

Java:

```
public class Encrypt {


    private Encrypt() {}

    public static String getURI() {
        String encryptedFinal = "";
        String userId = "userID";
        String pwd = "aBEMxY2c/UWpoQFGSWSabD=="; //24 chars long base64 key
        Date cDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        simpledateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        try
        {
            byte[] dBytes = simpledateformat.format(cDate).getBytes();

            byte[] bArray = Base64.decodeBase64(pwd.getBytes());
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(bArray, "AES");
            System.out.println(simpledateformat.format(date).toString());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(1, keySpec);
            byte[] cipher2 = cipher.doFinal(dBytes);
            byte[] cipher3 = cipher.doFinal("bloomberge.com/home".getBytes());
            encryptedFinal = "http://bloomberge.com/" + id + "&uri=" +
                    Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher3) + "&date=" +Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher2);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
        return encryptedFinal;
    }
}
```

NodeJS:

```
const { createCipheriv } = require('crypto')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const userID = "aBEMxY2c/UWpoQFGSWSabD=="; //24 chars long base64 key

const key = "aBEMxY2c/UWpoQFGSWSabD=="; //24 chars long base64 key
const tDate = new Date().toISOString().split('.')[0] + 'Z'

let cipher = createCipheriv('aes-128-ecm', Buffer.from(key, 'base64'), crypto.randomBytes(32)) //not sure if this is correct to read based 64 and how do I find correct iv length?. Getting the unknown cipher

let myTime = cipher.update(tDate, 'utf8', 'base64')
myTime += cipher.final('base64')

let tURI = createCipheriv('aes-128-ecm', Buffer.from(key, 'base64'), crypto.randomBytes(32)) //same unknown cipher, 

let tpURL = tURI.update(
    'bloomberg',
    'utf8',
    'base64'
)
tpURL += tURI.final('base64')

return (
    'myweburl' +
    userId +
    '&tURI=' +
    tpURL +
    '&tDateTime=' +
    myTime)
```

Getting error at first cipher here

```
let cipher = createCipheriv('aes-128-ecm', Buffer.from(key, 'base64'), crypto.randomBytes(32))
```

Error message:

> {"msg":"Unknown cipher","stack":"Error: Unknown cipher\n    at Cipheriv.createCipherBase (internal/crypto/cipher.js:103:19)\n    at Cipheriv.createCipherWithIV (internal/crypto/cipher.js:121:20)\n    at new Cipheriv (internal/crypto/cipher.js:227:22)\n    at createCipheriv (crypto.js:124:10)\n    at

Comment: Presumably the NodeJS counterpart is `aes-128-ecb`. The Base64 decoded key has a length of 16 bytes and therefore corresponds to AES-128. ecm doesn't exist afaik. `getInstance("AES")` in the Java code applies the provider-dependent default mode, generally ECB. ECB doesn't use an IV (and is therefore insecure).

Comment: Btw, you should fix the Java code so that it is compilable and executable.

Comment: Thank you @Topaco I will fix it and try it

Comment: in my case, it was caused by missing value for E_ALGO and E_KEY